# Таблица ASCII и её соответствие в c++

Tags: c++, ascii

Почему в таблице ASCII российская буква 'a' равна 160, а когда я пишу:

```
int a = 'а';

cout << a << endl;
```

мне выводит -32?

Comment: Тип `char` 8 bit signed, значения от -128 до 127, старший бит (определяет знак) при преобразовании в int распространяется влево, поэтому получается -32.

Comment: @avp: Думаю, стоит перенести в ответ. Я как раз начал писать почти то же самое.

Comment: @avp: В C тип литерала `'а'`, насколько мне помнится, `int`, там такого эффекта по идее не возникло бы.

Comment: @VladD, мой коммент на ответ не тянет, напишите Вы (если не лень).

Comment: @avp а как сделать, чтоб он оставался 160?  `unsigned char` или `unsigned int`?

Comment: Если менять по минимуму, то перед использованием приводить тип (операция cast) -- (unsigned char)'а'; Например, `printf("%d", (unsigned char)'a');` Конечно, можно `unsigned char uc = 'a'; printf("%d", uc);`

Comment: @avp интересные у Вас преобразования, однако. Да и `char` по Стандарту не обязан бы ни знаковым, ни 8 битовым.

Comment: @alexolut, хотите сказать что они не работают? А `char`, конечно, бывает и 16-bit и 32 (и ЕМНИП 64 в старом Cray). Бывает, наверное, и беззнаковый (лично таких компайлеров не встречал). Но, сейчас для ТС, он знаковый и 8-bit.

Comment: @avp ну, хотелось бы посмотреть как они работают. Вот Вы код привели с `printf`. А пробовали ли Вы его выполнить и получить желаемые ТС результаты? Беззнаковый `char` был в watcom под qnx 4.25.

Comment: @alexolut, он сработает (если locale для gcc будет cp866).

Comment: @avp это да, но тогда `-32` ни при делах. Прочитайте мой ответ, если ещё не читали.

Comment: @VladD то что в сях литерал будет иметь тип `int` [никак не повлияет](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MUR3LuWD4LLOOAVt) на знаковость `char`.

Comment: @alexolut, да тут ежу понятно, что ТС работает в cp1251, а задавая вопрос посмотрел на таблицу ascii с cp866 (a == 160 в выводе д.б. -96, а не -32, что соответствует а == 224 в cp1251)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Результат выполнения Вашего кода зависит от нескольких факторов. В частности от кодировки исходника, используемого компилятора и правил кодирования символьных и строковых литералов.

Например, возможен вариант вывода числа [`53424`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b9908fe1a6cd66a) и предупреждения:

> multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

при использовании `UTF-8` кодировки исходника и компилятора `gcc`. Т.о. `'а'` это вовсе и не символ, а целое число (более подробно о мультисимвольных литералах можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459939/what-do-single-quotes-do-in-c-when-used-on-multiple-characters)), в чем можно убедиться проверкой `sizeof`, которая [вернет](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb5762be22ad99d) такое же значение, как и для `int`, а не для `char` (по определению `1`).

При использовании `clang` вообще получим [ошибку](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fe010de1300f335) компиляции:

> character too large for enclosing character literal type

Чтобы избавиться от такой ошибки придется изменить тип символьного литерала (например на `wchar_t`, задав префикс `L`). В этом случае на выводе получим уже другое число: [`1072`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45dcef737e6a38a1), что соответствует [`UTF-16`](http://unicode-table.com/ru/0430/) коду русской буквы `а`.

Чтобы получить такой же результат как у Вас, но с помощью онлайн-компилятора `gcc` можно использовать ключ [`-fexec-charset`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/669a79a0bb952163) с кодовой страницей `1251`.

При этом, хочу заметить, что для буквы `а` код `160` (`0xA0`) соответствует кодировке [cp866](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#CP866), а не [cp1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B0_Windows-1251_.28.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BC_CP1251.29), в которой он равен `224` (`0xE0`). Поэтому `-32` в `160` превратиться не сможет путем обычного преобразования знакового числа в беззнаковое.

Если уж очень хочется получить на выводе именно `160` помимо преобразования в беззнаковый тип надо ещё использовать кодовую страницу cp866. Т.е. собирать следующий код с ключом [`-fexec-charset=cp866`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93e1dae7fd1f328e):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = static_cast<unsigned char>('а');
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: хороший анализ, +1

Comment: @ixSci да я сам много нового узнал пока ответ писал :)

Comment: Вот про `-fexec-charset=...` я и не знал. Спасибо (+1).

Answer (score 8):

Потому что число больше 127 не влезает в знаковый `char`, у которого диапазон от -128 до 127. Зато влезает в беззнаковый, но, судя по всему, на вашей системе `char` является знаковым, поэтому происходит конвертация из знакового `char` в знаковый `int`. Т.к. любое число `char` всегда влазит в `int`, то получается, что в `int` попадает отрицательное число из `char`

Чтобы получить положительное число, просто используйте любой `unsigned` тип в качестве приёмника значения, а исходный `char` преобразуйте к `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned int a = static_cast<unsigned char>('а');
```

Comment: Пример кода бы посмотреть :)

Comment: @alexolut, зачем? Так сложно подставить unsigned? Видимо, автору не сложно, т.к. он ответ принял.

Comment: Я о преобразовании `-32` в `160`.

Comment: @alexolut, это на совести автора. Я не высчитывал, что в каких кодировках находится — это, на мой взгляд, к вопросу не относится. Вопрос, на мой взгляд, о том, почему у человек отрицательное число, а не положительное.

Comment: Так не в кодировках дело, а в том, что `(unsigned char)(-32)` даст не `160`, а `224`.

Comment: Вы уж простите автора, но он еще совсем зеленый и некоторые моменты может упустить, мне для решения задачи `unsigned` помог все же)) 
Но прочитав статью @alexolut я все переосмыслил совсем))

Comment: @Vorobey.A, всё правильно, его ответ полнее и лучше.

Comment: @avp, веское замечание, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @ixSci, на самом деле `int a = static_cast<unsigned char>('а');` тоже будет работать. Поправьте уж еще разочек и удалим эти комментарии.

Comment: @avp, я сознательно оставил `unsigned int`, там может быть `unsigned char` — я просто привёл пример. `unsigned` должно хранится в `unsigned`

Comment: Зачем? Вовсе не обязательно. Зависит от задачи, а в данном случае просто лишние буковки. На самом деле IMHO важно то, что мы получим одинаковый результат для `char c; int i = (unsigned char)c;` и `char c; unsigned int u = (unsigned char)c;`

Comment: @avp лучше всё же `unsigned`, т.к. формально размер `char` и `int` может совпадать, а значит, не все значения `unsigned char` могут быть представимы в `int`.

Comment: @alexolut, формально да. Битики-то никуда не денутся, но интерпретироваться (при сравнении и индексации массивов) будут по разному. Правда, максимум, который можно записать в utf-8 (Unicode) это 31 бит, но теоретически... (ладно, пусть мучается).

Comment: @avp utf-8 символ может быть до 6 байт размером

Comment: @alexolut, ага,от 1 (7-битные коды) до 6 байт на символ (тут всюду 8-ми битные байты). И именно 6-байтные кодируют 31-битные коды (а вот 32 бита закодировать стандартным utf-8 не получится)