# Запись кириллицы в файл

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Каким образом записать кириллицу в файл? Смотрел на форумах там предлагают только просто отказаться от кириллицы и писать всё в транслите или латиницей. Хотелось бы рабочий пример.

Comment: Просто берете и пишете. Но нужно поминить, что кириллица кириллице разница, ибо кодировки. Скорее всего у Вас проблема не с тем, что бы записать, а проблема с непониманием, а что же записалось.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример с разными кодировками текста:

```
QFile file("file.txt");
if (file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)) {
    QTextStream stream(&file);

    stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
    stream << tr("Строка в UTF-8\n");
    stream.flush();

    stream.setCodec("Windows-1251");
    stream << tr("Строка в Windows-1251\n");
    stream.flush();
}
```

`stream.flush()` нужен для смены кодировки "на лету". Если этого не делать, то весь текст будет в последней, заданной, кодировке. В реалии этого, как правило, не требуется.

**UPDATE для Qt < 5.0**

Исходники должны быть в UTF-8. Кроме того, глобально задаем кодировку для `tr`:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

Если исходные тексты идут в других кодировках, то соответственно задаем другой кодек для `tr`, например:

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251"));
```

**UPDATE для Qt >= 5.0**

Начиная с Qt 5.0, ребята "кардинально" решили проблему с кодировками. Всё должно быть в UTF-8 и точка. Соответственно выпилили из исходников все `QTextCodec::setCodecForXXX`, кроме `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale`.

> For Qt’s own source code, we have decreed that the source should be
>   UTF-8 only, and so I proceeded a few weeks ago to find and recode all
>   non-UTF-8 sources. And I’m going even further than that: if you don’t
>   use UTF-8 for your source code, you’ll be on your own. Though it’s
>   possible to make it work, do not ask us for help and do not expect us
>   to add convenience functions. I am also discarding any arguments of
>   the form “my editor/IDE/OS/environment does not support UTF-8″.

Оригинал можно глянуть в блоге Thiago Macieira: [Source code must be UTF-8 and QString wants it](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/05/source-code-must-be-utf-8-and-qstring-wants-it/)

Comment: Работоспособность этого примера зависит от компилятора и его ключей, а также кодировки исходного файла.

Comment: @ixSci, исходники все в utf-8, компилятор gcc. Ключи тут особо не влияют, поскольку всю работу по перекодировке берет на себя Qt. Немного дополнил ответ

Comment: Ключи влияют, т.к. gcc можно сказать в какой кодировке исходник, и если сказать ему, что там cp1251 ANSI, а на деле там будет UTF-8, то получите ерунду на выходе.

Comment: @ixSci не только исходник, но и строковые литералы. Напомню [тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502412/176217).