# sizeof для символа кириллицы

Tags: c++, c, char, sizeof

Я провел несколько экспериментов, но объяснить почему это так работает я не смог

**Пример 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    /// латиница
    printf("\n%d",sizeof('a')); /// 1
    /// кириллица
    printf("\n%d",sizeof('ф')); /// 4
    return 0;
}
```

**Пример 2:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a = 'a'; /// латиница
    char b = 'ф'; /// кириллица
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(a)); /// 1
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(b)); /// 1
    return 0;
}
```

Вообще ничего не понимаю объясните!
P.S Компилятор g++

Comment: В первом случае Вы определяете размер символа, который может занимать больше одного байта (всякие UniCode). Втором размер поля типа char, который всегда 1 байт

Comment: @MaximPro  Покажите минимальный компилируемый пример, который демонстрирует данный результат.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow https://repl.it/EuJe/0 пожалуйста

Comment: @MaximPro Не указывайте ссылки, а приведите минимальную компилируемую программу, которую вы сами запускали, и которая демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow не вопрос, сейчас переделаю примеры

Comment: `sizeof` -- это не функция, а оператор. Да, и кто вас научил строку начинать с '\n'?

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите компилятор.

Comment: @0andriy да на самом деле никто, все равно код не идет в продакшн, а значит писать можно как угодно, религия не запрещает

Comment: Ну, моя религия говорит, либо ты делаешь тяп-ляп, либо всегда аккуратно. На качестве кода в продакшн сказывается неимоверно любой из этих подходов "для себя".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Символьные (и строковые) литералы в коде программы так или иначе переводятся компилятором в последовательность байт. Правило этого преобразования зависит от кодировки исходника (как уже упоминали другие участники), но может зависеть и ещё от ряда факторов (см. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502412/176217) на другой вопрос).

Следует заметить, что оба варианта Вашего кода при попытке компиляции компилятором *clang* [приводят к ошибке](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EjKtepKNp1bh4BwS):

> ```
> error: character too large for enclosing character literal type  
> char b = 'ф'; /// кириллица
> ```

А используемый Вами gcc [даёт пару предупреждений](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/r5cbxUFz6dxW4WUV) для строки с буквой `ф`:

> ```
> warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]  
> warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
> ```

Первое говорит об использовании мультисимвольного литерала (что поддерживается не всеми компиляторами). Второе - о том, что этот литерал не помещается в `char`. Т.е. тип `'ф'` компилятором был интерпретирован как нечто большее, чем `char`, и, как уже упоминалось в цитате из ответа @Harry, этот тип есть `int`:

> ... has type `int`, and has an implementation-defined value.

Исходя из вышесказанного, можно сделать вывод:

- `4` (пример 1) получается, т.к. мультисимвольный литерал не усекается и его размер равен размеру `int`, т.е. `sizeof(int) == 4`.
- `1` (пример 2) получается, т.к. мультисимвольный литерал был усечён до типа `char` при инициализации переменной `b`, а `sizeof(char) == 1` по определению.

---

Отвечу здесь и на Ваш комментарий к другому сообщению:

> я представлял себе многобайтовый литерал как один символ из сложной кодировки допустим 'ф' (UTF-8) а это 2 байта выходит мы можем по вашим словам записать не более 2х 'ф'...несостыковочка с 4мя символами

Записать более 2х `'ф'` у Вас действительно [не получится](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uEJkvKR736vU4Z2D).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("\n%d",sizeof('ффф')); 
}
```

> ```
> warning: character constant too long for its type
> ```

Т.е. фактически происходит усечение значения до `sizeof(int)`.

Но если будет использован **строковый** литерал, то для хранения `ф` вполне может хватить [двух байт](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/e9meVCD2wZJyqO1o):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const char c[] = "ф";
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(c)); 
}
```

> 3

Выводит число `3`, т.к. 1 байт отводится под терминирующий ноль.

Comment: Последнее переводится как: "Внимание: символьная константа слишком большая для этого типа"? И еще что значит усечение то есть сохранится только 2 символа? И если да то как эти 2 символа напечатать? Какой вообще практический смысл?

Comment: И еще непонятно по какому принципу выводится результат?
`printf("%u - %u\n%u - %u", sizeof('2'), '2', sizeof('22'), '22'); /// 1 - 50
4 - 12850`

Comment: @MaximPro Усечение, это когда Вы например пытаетесь число `1000` присвоить переменной типа `char`. Как оно реально усечется зависит от компилятора, но скорее всего просто [отбросит первые символы](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ap989pxzmy3eIq6r). Напечатать любой участок памяти можно по байтам, через `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @MaximPro `12850 = 50 * 256 + 50`

Comment: Вы не до конца ответили на мой первый вопрос к вашему ответу. Как кстати получилась такая формула? Я понимаю что 1 байт это 256 значений, но не понимаю действия производимые в этой формуле!

Comment: @MaximPro очень легко! Имеем два байта: старший и младший, в каждом хранится значение `50`, когда эти байты объединяются в единое число, то получается `12850` по упомянутой формуле. В бинарном виде `50` - это `00110010`. Объединяем, получим `0011001000110010`, что есть `12850`.

Comment: @MaximPro преобразование многобайтового символа в `int` зависит от компилятора. В данном случае (и чаще всего) оно работает как я описал.

Comment: За формулу спасибо и объяснение к ней тоже +!

Comment: @MaximPro не забудьте принять ответ, который считаете наиболее подходящим!

Comment: Насчет усечения! Усекается только спереди или сзади тоже может усекаться? Смысл от мультисимвольного литерала? Ну допустим есть у нас 'фф' и мы его даже распечатать не можем! Что вообще с этим делать?

Comment: @MaximPro боле подробно про многобайтовый символьный литерал можете посмотреть в [теме на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7459939/3240681). Эта тема упоминается в другом моем ответе, на который я давал ссылку в текущем ответе. Развивать активное обсуждение в комментариях здесь не приветствуется. Поэтому, либо создайте новую тему по новым вопросам, либо можно переместиться в чат.

Comment: уже почитал =) Но по-факту там ничего интересного кроме того как описано представление многобайтного литерала в 16м формате

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50448/discussion-between-maximpro-and-alexolut).

Answer (score 15):

`sizeof` - формально не функция, а оператор, который еще во время компиляции дает размер типа - т.е. сколько памяти требуется для хранения переменной данного типа.

Судя по тому, что для латинского литерала `'a'` вы получили значение 1, вы компилируете не как C, а как C++! В чистом C литерал символа приводится к типу `int`, и вы бы получили 4.

Приходится также полагать, что исходник у вас сохранен как utf-8, например, так что кириллица раскрывается в нечто большее, чем `char`, и это нечто приводится к `int` и дает 4.

Последние же строки получают не литерал, а переменную типа `char`, а для нее в C++ однозначно - `sizeof(char) == 1`.

Вот и все...

P.S. Поскольку некоторые настаивают... :) Из стандарта о символьных литералах:

> An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char representable in the execution character set has type char, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set. An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character set, is conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an implementation-defined value.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51296/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-sizeof---).

Answer (score 4):

Тип однобайтового символьного литерала `'q'` - это `char`, `sizeof(char)` равен 1.

Тип многобайтового символьного литерала `'qq'` - это `int`, `sizeof(int)` это например 4.

Если исходники сохраняются в кодировке utf-8, то литерал `'ф'` это два байта, он эквивалентен `'\xd1\x84'`. Соответственно его тип - `int`.

Comment: qq - это уже 2 символа, это уже какой-то строковый литерал

Comment: кстати мне кажется вы ошиблись с шестнадцатиричным кодом не `'\xd1\x84'` а `'\xd4\x84'`

Comment: @MaximPro [ф](https://unicode-table.com/ru/0444/). Строковый литерал задаётся двойными кавычками.

Comment: @alexolut и чем различается многобайтовый символьный литерал от строкового литерала? (Кроме различия кавычек)

Comment: @MaximPro строковый может содержать любое кол-во символов, многобайтовый символьный - не более 4х.

Comment: @alexolut и почему не более 4?

Comment: @MaximPro потому что `sizeof(int)` обычно 4.

Comment: @alexolut что-то я совсем запутался, я представлял себе многобайтовый литерал как один символ из сложной кодировки допустим 'ф' (UTF-8) а это 2 байта выходит мы можем по вашим словам записать не более 2х 'ф'...несостыковочка с 4мя символами