# Получить hex значение символа кириллицы c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Имеется:

```
char s1 = 'Ю';
wchar_t s2 = 'ж';
```

Необходимо в буфер `char*` или `wchar_t*` поместить hex-значение этих символов.
Т.е. необходимо получить: **%d0%ae** и **%d0%b6**
Как это правильно сделать?
Максимум, что удалось получить - **042E** и **0436**. Дальше - не знаю как...

**Доп.-1**: Как я получаю 0436 по символу 'ж':

```
wchar_t test_string[] = L"жизнь";
unsigned long ul = test_string[0];
wchar_t hex_buffer[32];
swprintf(hex_buffer, L"0%02x", ul);
```

В результате получаем **0436**, что в таблице [UTF-символов](https://web-developer.name/urlcode/) соответствует маленькой буквой "ж".
Теперь необходимо получить hex-значение этого символа, опять же из таблицы - **%d0%b6** в буфер `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Кириллический символ не вместится в `char`, т.к. занимает не 1, а 2 байта.

Comment: @LLENN, смотря в какой кодировке, в 866 и 1251 вместится, автор же не пишет, что он делает

Comment: @LLENN, UTF8, encodeURIComponent

Comment: @PavelGridin, в вопросе же пример есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy из однобайтового `s1` два байта получить нельзя. Если, конечно не заниматься тупо преобразованием из одной кодировки в другую. Автору рекомендую посмотреть [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502412/176217) по очень похожей проблеме. И ещё [один другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606056/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я так понимаю, он хочет закодированную под url строку, т. е. был один символ `Ы`, а стало 6 символов `%D0%AB`. В однобайтовый char отлично влезет, потому что остаются только ascii-символы (впрочем, в большем количестве).

Comment: @Qwertiy в вопросе ТС впихивает (пытается) кириллическую `Ю` в один байт, это значит, что кодировка исходника у него какая-то однобайтовая, иначе будут ворнинги как минимум (нужно ещё уточнить какой компилятор используется и с какими ключами сборки). Но на этом фоне будет странно смотреться другая строка с буквой `ж`. При этом получить из однобайтовой кодировки одиночного символа пару байт - это уже перекодировка. Т.е. надо знать исходную и целевую кодировки. В вопросе они не указаны, поэтому я рекомендую его закрыть как неясный.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, целевая - UTF8. Это вопрос о encodeURIComponent. По тексту вопроса поместить надо в буфер, т. е. в строку, т. е. ограничения на число символов нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy "Это вопрос о encodeURIComponent." <- это ваши додумки. И такого нет в c++.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ уточняю: это вопрос про то, как сделать операцию url-кодирования на c++

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и да, обе строчки кода из вопроса автора - корректны (хотя в зависимости от платформы могут делать совершенно не то что задумал автор).

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну вот чтобы корректность кода превратилась в корректность вопроса, хотелось бы чтоб автор привёл как минимум вариант кода, где он получает `042E` и `0436`.

Comment: Случай с char - отбросим, хорошо. Как получить код символа и поместить его в wchar_t? Вопрос дополнил.

Comment: UTF-8 - кодирока кодируется как `char*` - однобайтная, несмотря на то, что двумя символами может кодироваться один. Касательно винды - переведите в unicode а за тем в `char*` через ф-цию `WideCharToMuliByte` Почитайте вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897222/c-curl-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-utf-8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5/900948#900948

Comment: Изучая таблицы кодирования UTF-символов, я обнаружил несколько закономерностей. Написал пару формул расчёта, и в результате получилось вычислить сначала десятичное представление первого октета с последующим переводом его в hex, а затем вычислил значение и второго октета, чего вполне должно хватить для преобразования кириллицы в UTF-8 hex. Расчёт значения и первого и второго октета основан на зависимости от десятичного значения символа. А дальше - сплошная арифметика :) Спасибо всем отписавшимся, но т.к. ни одно решение не оказалось рабочим, пришлось писать собственную реализацию.

Comment: Да, по формуле можно. Без формулы - нужно два вызова - MultiByteToWideChar а потом WideCharToMuliByte. Но... возможно формулой проще.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно преобразовать строку в UTF-8 перед тем, как получать hex-представление. Можно использовать, например, [codecvt_utf8_utf16](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/codecvt-utf8-utf16-class?view=vs-2015):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

    wchar_t wide_str[] = L"жизнь";  
    wchar_t hex_buffer[256] = L"";
    wchar_t buf[32];

    //преобразуем строку в UTF-8
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> utf16conv;  
    auto utf8_str = utf16conv.to_bytes(wide_str);

    //преобразуем UTF-8 в hex-представление
    for(int i=0;i<utf8_str.length();i++){   
        swprintf(buf, L"%%%x",(unsigned int)(unsigned char)(utf8_str.c_str()[i]));
        wcscat(hex_buffer,buf);
    }
    wprintf(L"%s = %s\n",wide_str,hex_buffer);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
// Результат:
//
// жизнь = %d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8c
```

Comment: `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16` - deprecated в C++17